# How to subclass a Stimulus controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, import-maps

I want to subclass one of my Stimulus controllers but I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/parent_controller.js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus'
export default class ParentController extends Controller {
  // ...
}

// app/javascript/controllers/child_controller.js
import ParentController from './parent_controller.js'
export default class extends ParentController {
  // ...
}
```

In the browser's console I get:

```
Failed to register controller: child (controllers/child_controller) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/controllers/child_controller-[digest].js
```

What am I doing wrong?

(This is using Rails 7 with importmaps.)

Comment: My guess is it's a circular import error. Try renaming the child controller file to start with a letter after P. If that works it may indicate it was a circular import issue. You will most likely need to add your parent controller to an external file that's imported in both controller files.

Comment: @LBBenJohnston Thanks, that's a good idea.  Unfortunately it didn't work though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not using the importmap correctly.  This is the solution:

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/parent_controller.js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus'
export default class extends Controller {
}

// app/javascript/controllers/child_controller.js
import ParentController from 'controllers/parent_controller'
export default class extends ParentController {
}
```

The child controller needs to import the parent from `"controllers/parent_controller"`, which is the name used by the importmap, given the following default:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```